# How to restructure JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

I have a JSON file that comes in a particular structure (see Sample A), but  I need it too be structured like Sample B.

Is it possible to reorganise the data in JS? If so, how do you go about this?

Sample A:

```
   var myData = [
      {
        "date": "01/01/2017",
        "here-value": "20",
        "here-color": "pink",
        "there-value": "24",
        "there-color": "red",
      },
      {
        "date": "02/01/2017",
        "here-value": "80",
        "here-color": "blue",
        "there-value": "54",
        "there-color": "red",
      },
    ]
```

Sample B:

```
  var myData = [

    {
      "date": "01/01/2017",
      "here-value": "20",
      "here-color": "pink"
    },
    {
      "date": "01/01/2017",
      "there-value": "24",
      "there-color": "red"
    },

    {
      "date": "02/01/2017",
      "here-value": "80",
      "here-color": "blue"
    },
    {
      "date": "02/01/2017",
      "there-value": "54",
      "there-color": "red"
    }

]
```

The reason I'm seeking to restructure the data, is to create objects that will feed into a visualisation using D3. 
The result will be similar to: http://jsfiddle.net/vw88/nzwLg96a/

Comment: the expected structure is wrong, try by pasting in developer's window, it will throw error

Comment: Without more context, it's impossible to say which is the best choice. It depends on how you're going to use the data.

Comment: Appreciate the responses. I've just updated the question to correct the JSON and also provide context. The application for the JSON file can be seen in the JS Fiddle.

Comment: If the keys are the same in all objects in the array, nothing is stopping you from mapping it to a new one. By the way, you’re working with a native jQuery object... not a JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var sampleA = [
    {
    "date": "01/01/2017",
    "here-value": "20",
    "here-color": "pink",
    "there-value": "24",
    "there-color": "red",
    },
    {
    "date": "02/01/2017",
    "here-value": "80",
    "here-color": "blue",
    "there-value": "54",
    "there-color": "red",
    },
]


var sampleB = [];
sampleA.forEach( i => {
    let a = {};
    a.date = i.date;
    a['here-value'] = i['here-value'];
    a['here-color'] = i['here-color'];
    let b = {};
    b.date = i.date;
    b['there-value'] = i['there-value'];
    b['there-color'] = i['there-color'];
    sampleB.push(a, b);
});
console.log(sampleB);
```

Answer (score 4):

Thought I would include this approach as-well using Array.reduce()

```
let restructuredData = myData.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.concat([
        { "date": b["date"], "here-value": b["here-value"],  "here-color": b["here-color"] },
        { "date": b["date"], "there-value": b["there-value"],  "there-color": b["there-color"] }
    ]);
}, []);
```

Comment: Love this solution, it's extremely concise and readable :) +1

Answer (score 1):

This also working,

```
var myData = [
      {
        "date": "01/01/2017",
        "here-value": "20",
        "here-color": "pink",
        "there-value": "24",
        "there-color": "red",
      },
      {
        "date": "02/01/2017",
        "here-value": "80",
        "here-color": "blue",
        "there-value": "54",
        "there-color": "red",
      },
    ] ;

  var newAr = [];

  myData.forEach(function(val, key){
    newAr.push({"date": val.date, "here-value": val["here-value"],
        "here-color": val["here-color"]});
    newAr.push({"date": val.date, "there-value": val["there-value"],
        "there-color": val["there-color"]});
  })

  console.log("newAr:", newAr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myData = [{
    "date": "01/01/2017",
    "here-value": "20",
    "here-color": "pink",
    "there-value": "24",
    "there-color": "red",
  },
  {
    "date": "02/01/2017",
    "here-value": "80",
    "here-color": "blue",
    "there-value": "54",
    "there-color": "red",
  },
]

var newData = []
myData.forEach(b => {

  newData.push({
    date: b.date,
    "here-value": b["here-value"],
    "here-color": b["here-color"],
  }, {
    date: b.date,
    "there-value": b["there-value"],
    "there-color": b["there-color"],
  })

});
console.log(newData);
```